# Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

Say I have a bunch of names in a array and I want to post this data to another url on my site, but the post data will be "name="+name+"&name="+name+""; etcetc

So for each name i need to generate another name= to add to post data until there are no more names

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can map every element in the array to the same thing with `name=` prepended, and then join them with the `&` character.

```
return names.map(function(name) {
    return "name=" + name;
}).join("&");
```

If you need to support browsers that don't have the `map` method on `Array` (it requires JS 1.6), you can pinch it from [the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or just use a `for` loop instead.

```
var queryBits = [];
for (var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
    queryBits.push("name=" + names[i]);
}
return queryBits.join("&");
```

Comment: You should mention that `map` is not available in all browsers... *edit: +1 for a more complete solution*

Comment: @Felix: I realised that right after I hit "Submit". Edited to include the information.

Comment: @lonesomeday: That's a good point. @joe, you can wrap name in the `escape` function to make sure there are no dodgy characters in your query string: `return "name=" + escape(name);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery param() to serialize an array to post it in a url. look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for reference. It's very useful becouse it encodes automatically your data.

Comment: He could, but is it worth including the whole library only for using this function?

Comment: well, if you just use the library for one page you can include the library only on that page. (and i like using jQuery because it's easier and you don't have to worry too much about browser compatibility)